# Arduino Nano with ESP8266 problems

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

this is my first post here because I'm a bit lost at the moment.
I currently have my ESP8266-01 hocked up to the Nano like this:

[image: wiring]

The issue I'm having is that it won't even turn on, only when I'm using the 3.3V pin the red led on the ESP8266 turns on. If connected to 3.3V and I connect the CH_PD pin to 3.3V aswell, the blue led flashes 2-3 times and then the ESP8266 turns off.

I hope someone is able to help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: for some reason i thought this question was in electrical engineering. +1 to close even though I answered.

Comment: You can also try [arduino.stackexchange.com](https://arduino.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your fritzing diagram isn't the clearest. But from what I can interpret you need to do this for the ESP8266-

VCC should be connected to 3.3V
CH_PD should be connected or pulled to 3.3V
REST should be pulled to 3.3V. I see no mention of the REST pin so this is most likely the issue.